# Three js black outline effect with white textures

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to do an outline effect like below in threejs ?
[image]

I've looked at the threeJs examples and tried the following:

1. FilmPass with Gamma Correction and Outline Effect. But the darker textures come dark. I want to just have the outline with no grays [image]

```
        this.composer.addPass(filmPass);
        var gammaCorrection = new ShaderPass(GammaCorrectionShader);
        this.composer.addPass(gammaCorrection);
        var outlinePass = new OutlinePass( new Three.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ), this.scene3D, this.camera);
        this.composer.addPass( outlinePass );

        this.composer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
```

2. Sobel Operator Shader - but that makes the textures dark with outline white
   [image]

```
        var effectSobel = new ShaderPass( SobelOperatorShader );
        effectSobel.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.x = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
        effectSobel.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.y = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
        this.composer.addPass( effectSobel );
```

Any help/hint in greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/ldraw-like-edges/17100

Comment: Thanks, this is a great resource. The example here https://gkjohnson.github.io/threejs-sandbox/conditional-lines/ though seems to be cloning the original mesh and adding a new edge based mesh to achieve this. I was wondering if there was anything that might simply have a post processing to allow this effect rather than having to create a clone of every mesh in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   mesh.add(
      new THREE.LineSegments(
          geometry,
          new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
              color: 'black',
              transparent: false,
              opacity: 0.5
          })
      )
    );
```

replace `mesh` with whatever the name of mesh is. play around with the transparency and opacity until you get the desired result.